# Select Query combining a group select querys in PL/SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am new to Oracle can any one explain to how to achieve the below task please

Query in SQlserver2008:

Input:

```
Select

(Select 'a') a,

(Select 'b') b,

(Select 'c') c


output: a   b   c 
        a   b   c
```

How can I do the same in Oracle (pl/sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use for this dual table:

```
select 'a' as A, 'b' as B, 'c' as C
from dual;
```

of your actual query:

```
Select 
    (Select count() from table1) area1, 
    (Select count() from table2) area2, 
    (Select count(*) from table3) area3 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know how to create an alias for a column, like so :

```
SELECT 'a' AS "This is an a" FROM DUAL;
```

This would give the output

```
This is an a
a
```

You can give multiple aliases to multiple columns the same way:

```
SELECT 'a' AS "This is an a", 'b' AS "but this is a b" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: My actual sql query is    "Select

(Select count(*) from table1) area1,

(Select count(*) from table2) area2,

(Select count(*) from table3) area3" can we convert this as oracle query so that it can run in PL/SQL Developer.